# Event triggered in Microsoft Teams when a user updated its profile picture

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to get the updated profile picture of a user whenever he/she updates it or remove it. Is there any event in Microsoft teams bot that gets triggered whenever a user does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no event triggered to the Bot when a user updates the profile picture. You could use the [Get Photo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) Graph API to get the profile photo of the user.

Comment: How will a user get to know the profile picture is being updated of another user in the same workspace? Can you suggest something for this?